# Examples of accessing files on a OneDrive using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, excel, ms-word

I am looking for examples of accessing files residing on a OneDrive from a web page using JavaScript or JQuery or even Angular JS. I assume that the "path to the file", "the user ID" and "password" is needed to open (access) the user's account (Hotmail, Office 365, Live, Outlook) and open the specific file.

The goal is for opening an Excel or Word file using a service that will access the file using OOXML SDK to extract information for one or more specific xml part files in the DOCX, XLSX, or XLSM file.

Comment: Hello - were you able to get this working?  If so, how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a full documentation about the OneDrive API at MSDN, including examples of how to Download, Upload, Delete, etc.

You should take a look here:

[MSDN - OneDrive API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826521.aspx)